# Spring Security OAuth2 Change JSON Error Response Format

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I have a Spring Security OAuth2 based RESTful application. I have been trying to change the default Spring Security messaging formats from XML to JSON and have been partially successful in doing so.

For eg - I figured out how to change the response format when the request does not contain Bearer token (the following line does it)

```
<bean id="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint" class ="c.s.m.security.CustomAuthenticationEntryPoint" />
```

But I am not able to figure out how to catch/change the format of the below two items.

1. When an invalid token is being passed in the secured URL, Spring Security currently throws back. Where do I change this format?

   ```
   {"error": "invalid_token","error_description": "Invalid access token: 144285e3-9563-420e-8ce"}
   ```
2. How do I change the BadCredentialsException JSON format? Currently, it returns a JSON similar to above?

Below is my applicationContext.xml

```
<sec:http pattern="/oauth/token" create-session="stateless"
    use-expressions="true" authentication-manager-ref="authenticationManager">
    <sec:csrf disabled="true" />
    <sec:anonymous enabled="false" />
    <sec:http-basic entry-point-ref="clientAuthenticationEntryPoint" />
    <sec:custom-filter ref="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter" before="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER" />
    <sec:access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" />
</sec:http>
<sec:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager"
    erase-credentials="false">
    <sec:authentication-provider user-service-ref="clientDetailsUserService" />
</sec:authentication-manager>

<bean id="clientDetailsUserService" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientDetailsUserDetailsService">
    <constructor-arg ref="clientDetails" />
</bean>

<!-- Entry point - Entry point Filter for token server -->

<bean id="clientAuthenticationEntryPoint" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <property name="realmName" value="Oauth 2 security" />
    <property name="typeName" value="Basic" />
</bean>

<bean id="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter">
    <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
</bean>

<!-- Oauth handler Access Denied Handler -->

<bean id="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" class="c.s.m.security.CustomAccessDeniedHandler" />
    <!-- class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler" /> -->

<!-- Server resource -->

<sec:http pattern="/api/**" create-session="never"
    entry-point-ref="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint" use-expressions="true" >
    <sec:csrf disabled="true" />
    <sec:anonymous enabled="false" />
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/api/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />
    <sec:custom-filter ref="resourceServerFilter"
        before="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" />
    <sec:access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" />
</sec:http>

<!-- Entry point resource -->

<bean id="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint" class ="c.s.m.security.CustomAuthenticationEntryPoint" />          

<oauth:resource-server id="resourceServerFilter" resource-id="springsec" token-services-ref="tokenServices" />

<bean id="tokenServices"
    class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.DefaultTokenServices" >
    <property name="tokenStore" ref="tokenStore" />
    <property name="supportRefreshToken" value="true" />
    <property name="accessTokenValiditySeconds" value="300000" />
    <property name="clientDetailsService" ref="clientDetails" />
</bean>    
<bean id="tokenStore"  class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.JdbcTokenStore">
    <constructor-arg ref="dataSource" />
</bean>
<oauth:authorization-server client-details-service-ref="clientDetails" token-services-ref="tokenServices">
    <oauth:authorization-code />
    <oauth:implicit />
    <oauth:refresh-token />
    <oauth:client-credentials />
    <oauth:password authentication-manager-ref="userAuthenticationManager" />
</oauth:authorization-server>

<sec:authentication-manager id="userAuthenticationManager">
    <sec:authentication-provider ref="customUserDetailsService" />
</sec:authentication-manager>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to force Spring Security OAuth 2 to use JSON instead of XML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33929788/how-to-force-spring-security-oauth-2-to-use-json-instead-of-xml)

Answer (score 0):

Send `Accept: application/json` in the request header will solve the problem.